# Let RichFaces calendar's drop down menu be always opened

Tags: calendar, richfaces

Usually the [RichFaces calendar widget](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=calendar&sample=calendar&skin=blueSky) drop down menu, that helps the user choosing a date, appears only if you click this widget's icon. Is there a chance to have this drop down menu be opened by default? I want the user to always see all dates as I want to add some meta information for each day, e. g. coloring.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here we go. Setting `popup` to `false` is the answer.

```
<rich:calendar value="#{bean.selectedDate}" id="calendar" locale="de_DE" 
       popup="false" datePattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm" cellWidth="24px" cellHeight="22px">
</rich:calendar>
```